# htaccess prevent hotlinking image specific file name structure

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I have the following in an .htaccess file and it works fine:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpg)$ /noimageforyou [NC,R,L]
```

This prevents hotlinking of all images. However, I am actually OK with hot linking *some* images. I am using WordPress, and when you upload an image it will create various image sizes, example:

- imagefile.jpg (original)
- imagefile-150x150.jpg
- imagefile-300x400.jpg

I am happy to allow hot linking of the smaller image sizes, just not the original. I am wondering if there is a way to refine the htaccess to exclude all as it does now but then allow any filename with #x#.jpg in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a condition to filter out the smaller images:

```bash
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?domain.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-\d+x\d+\.jpg # Check the end of the filename only - we don't need the beginning part for this check
RewriteRule \.(jpg)$ /noimageforyou [NC,R,L]
```